# All Users from in LDAP in JAVA

Tags: java, c#, ldap

i want to fetch all active Users from an LDAP. The LDAP has way over 1k Users (afaik you can only take 1k Users from Ldap in one request). 
When using C# i used this:

```
//Open connection to LDAP Server

using (var directoryEntry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP"****************",
            {
                using (var directorySearcher = new DirectorySearcher(directoryEntry)
                {
                    PageSize = 1000,
                    Filter = "****************",
                    SearchScope = System.DirectoryServices.SearchScope.Subtree,
                    PropertiesToLoad =
                    {
                       ***,
                       ***,
                       ...
                    }
                })
                {
                    using (SearchResultCollection src = directorySearcher.FindAll())
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            foreach (SearchResult sr in src)
                            {
                                //Create User and add to a List of Users
```

Now i have to do the same but in Java code. What i tried is this:

```
NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> results = ctx.search(ldapSearchBase, searchFilter, searchControls);

        SearchResult searchResult = null;

        while (results.hasMoreElements()) {
            searchResult = (SearchResult) results.nextElement();

            //Create User from searchResult Attributes and add to a List
        }
```

When this Java code finishes, i have a List with 1k Users, so the problem is obviously that only 1k Users get fetched.

The Question:

How do i tell Java to fetch 1k Users -> write to a List -> get the next 1k until there are no more Users left to fetch.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to a relative similar question can be found in answer #1 in this thread:

[Retrieving user attributes from Active Directory using LDAP - JAVA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9081587/retrieving-user-attributes-from-active-directory-using-ldap-java?rq=1)

BR

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on the LDAP directory that you are using. I assume that it is Active Directory if you were using C#. This [post](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1157644?tstart=0) describes how to use the paged results control to avoid hitting the 1000 limit.

And no, the 1000 limit is not universal across all LDAP server implementations. It is a limit that Active Directory is using by default. The alternative to using the paged results control would be to increase the [MaxPageSize](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770976(v=ws.11).aspx) limit.